# How to show consistence of a estimator

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, statistical-inference, bayesian

PDF of a random  variable $X$ is,
$$
\begin{equation}
    f\left(x|\gamma\right)= 
    \begin{cases}
         e^{-(x-\gamma)} & x\geq\gamma\\
         0 & \text{otherwise.}
    \end{cases}
\end{equation}
$$

Given a sample of $n$ i.i.d observations $\mathbf{x}=$ $\left(x_{1}, \ldots, x_{n}\right)$ from this distribution,

(a) Show that the estimator $\hat{\gamma} = \overline{X} - 1$ (where $\overline{X} = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$) is an unbiased and consistent estimator for the given distribution.

Try:

\begin{align*}
    E[X_1]& \stackrel{\text{using def.}}{=} \gamma+ 1
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
    \mathbb E[\hat{\gamma}] &= \mathbb E[\overline{X} - 1]\\
    &= \mathbb E\left[\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i\right]-1\\
    &= \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb E[X_i] -1 \\
    &=  \frac{1}{n} (n\gamma+ n) -1\\
    &= \gamma
\end{align*}

Is it enough to say the esimator is unbiased? I couldn't understand how to show the consistence. As the [definition is](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consistent_estimator#Definition),

> An estimator $T_n$ of parameter $\theta$ is said to be consistent, if it converges in probability to the true value of the parameter:
> $$\lim_{n\to \infty }T_{n}\stackrel{p}{=}\theta.$$ i.e. if, for all $\epsilon>0$
> $$\lim_{n\to \infty }P(|T_n-\theta|>\epsilon)=0$$

The definition is quite complicated (to convergence in probability). I guess chebyshev's inequality can play a role here, but couldn't link that.

Any help will be appreciated. TIA.

Comment: Which parameter do you try to estimate? Estimator $\hat{\theta}$ for the parameter $\theta$ is called unbiased if $\mathbb{E}[\hat{\theta}]=\theta$. I don't understand that did you mean by saying "Estimator for the distribution".

Answer (score 1):

You computations for the unbiasedness are correct. to show the consistency we use Chebickev Inequality.

First we observe that $\text{Var}(\hat{\gamma})=\text{Var}(\bar{X}_n-1)=\text{Var}(\bar{X}_n)=1/n$. Then (here $T_n = \hat{\gamma}$ and $\theta = \gamma$)

$$
\mathbb{P}(\mid \hat{\gamma} - \gamma \mid > \epsilon) = \mathbb{P}(\mid \hat{\gamma} - \mathbb{E}(\gamma) \mid > \epsilon) \le \frac{1}{\epsilon^2n^2}
$$

which indeed tends to zero when $n \to \infty$.

*Proof of Chebyshev's Inequality*

Let $Y:=(X - \mathbb{E}(X))^2$ and $\epsilon > 0$. Since $Y$ is a nonnegative rv we can apply Markov to it, so

$$
\mathbb{P}(Y \ge \epsilon^2) \le \frac{\mathbb{E}(Y)}{\epsilon^2} = \frac{\mathbb{E}[(X - \mathbb{E}(X))^2]}{\epsilon^2} = \frac{\text{Var}(X)}{\epsilon^2}
$$

Finally we obtain the desired inequality noticing that

$$
\mathbb{P}(Y \ge \epsilon^2) = \mathbb{P}((X - \mathbb{E}(X))^2 \ge \epsilon^2) = \mathbb{P}(|X - \mathbb{E}(X)| \ge \epsilon)
$$

Comment: Can you expand your calculation a little bit. I knew chebyshev inequality with $k\sigma$ threshold. Can you expand it for $\epsilon$? And Is there any bound for $\epsilon$? Like gauss inequality did?

Comment: @MLearner there's not much to add actually. it is a version of the chebyshev inequality. I added a proof of that version